# In Mvc, while using RedirectToAction("ReqAction", odetails) getting err as "Input is not a valid base 64 string as it contains non base 64 character"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, base64, httppostedfilebase

If passed without the object its works fine by

```
return RedirectToAction("ReqAction");
```

In model used `public HttpPostedFileBase Provisionforattachment { get; set; }` to store the file in database.

Converted to bytes in the previous model to store the file in database.

```
byte[] UploadedFile = new byte[oPModelViewObject.Provisionforattachment.InputStream.Length];                         
oPModelViewObject.Provisionforattachment.InputStream.Read(UploadedFile, 0, UploadedFile.Length);
```

Tried several times its working fine when the file not uploaded.

Is the error happening because of the object containing Provisionforattachment of type HTTPPostedFileBase. Can anyone suggest to redirect with the object.

Answer (score 0):

Why are taking in model just take string in model to save only file name then its directly posted to your controller and you can store it to server by below code

```
String TempFileName;
HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection = Request.Files[0];
TempFileName = "C:\\TempFiles\\File_" + MyFileCollection.FileName .ToString();
// Save the file.
MyFileCollection.SaveAs(TempFileName);
```

refere below parameter to pass your currect value

RedirectToAction(String)
Redirects to the specified action using the action name.

RedirectToAction(String, Object)
Redirects to the specified action using the action name and route values.

RedirectToAction(String, String)
Redirects to the specified action using the action name and controller name.

RedirectToAction(String, RouteValueDictionary)
Redirects to the specified action using the action name and route dictionary.

RedirectToAction(String, String, Object)
Redirects to the specified action using the action name, controller name, and route dictionary.

RedirectToAction(String, String, RouteValueDictionary)
Redirects to the specified action using the action name, controller name, and route values.

Comment: Wanted to save the file in database and RedirectToAction(String, Object) dint work

Comment: which databas are you using you cant save file in database you need to upload file to server and you can store file path to database